# Importing a bunch of btc private keys into bitcoin core, then monitoring and sweeping them all to another address?

Tags: json-rpc, sendtoaddress, sweep

I'm trying to build a service where I import a bunch of pirvate keys into bitcoin core or some other software if you recommend a better solution. Once the private keys are imported, I want to *monitor* these addresses and if anything is positive have it send it to another wallet address I own.

I thought aboout importing the private keys with *importprivkey* api call. Does it take multiple private keys or do I have to loop through them?

Once these private keys are imported into my wallet I want to be able to detect the occurrence of any of the following:

- if the entire wallet balance is greater than .001
- or if 1 hour passes

Then, send all coins in the wallet to another address. My questions are:

- Is there a service to monitor the bitcoin balance, or do I just have to make a cron job to query it every second?
- When using *sendtoaddress* api call, do I have to specify a change address?
- How do other people usually solve this problem?

Comment: That seems completely pointless. Why not give the target address in the first place then? Aren't you just generating a fee burden for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using sendtoaddress api call, do I have to specify a change address?

No, it generates a new key pair and sends the balance to it. This key pair is stored in your wallet.dat file.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a service to monitor the bitcoin balance, or do I just have
>   to make a cron job to query it every second?

I do not know such service. Anyway, you should not give your private keys for any service.

> When using sendtoaddress api call, do I have to specify a change
>   address?

Why do you want to use bitcoin client and api calls for it?

> How do other people usually solve this problem?

This is not a "problem". This is a "task". You should monitor transactions in the network and push your transactions which sweep the outputs to your address. I can provide you such toolkit, but not for free